# How to access instagram images

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I have an application in which i want to get images from instagram or cameraroll and then use that images. How to pick images from instagram?

Comment: What do you mean by picking images from Instagram? if you mean getting images from Instagram application on device, then it's not possible. You can access user images from Instagram using it's API, I'm afraid that's the only way to get images from Instagram.

Comment: i want to access images globally. that can be of any user

Answer (score 3):

You can access instagram images in your iOS app only by using instagramAPI.
 If you are not familiar with Social media integration in iOS, please be aware that any social media integration in iOS  requires the respective API .
You should start with their docs [instagramAPI](http://instagram.com/developer/) .The way to access is also described [here](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/).

Comment: Removed, the API is capable for it now. Doesn't need any third party library.

Answer (score 1):

you can check this easy framework https://github.com/Busta117/SBInstagram

you can change when the user tap over the image and get your UIimage to use it where do you want.